# structured binding initializer inside if statement does not compile

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Reading up on C++17 and now multiple initializations inside if statement is possible:

```
if (int x = func(), y = func2(); x > 0 && y > 0)
{
}
```

Nice one, also in combination with another feature in C++17, structured bindings:

```
if (auto[iter, success] = set.insert("Hello"); success)
{   }
else    
{   }
```

But combining both features does not compile in VisualStudio 2017.

```
if (auto[iter, success] = set.insert("Hello"), [iter2, success2] = set.insert("Foo"); success && success2)
{}
else
{}
```

> missing ';' before ','

Is this is a bug in VS2017 or is this not possible?

Comment: `auto [iter, success, iter2, success2] = std::tuple_cat(set.insert("Hello"), set.insert("Foo"))`

Comment: Strictly speaking this has nothing to do with the new `if` initializer declaration. This won't work outside an `if` too..

Comment: `auto` isnt always the same as `auto`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MSVC is right on the money in this one. This stems for the grammar alone:

```
selection-statement:  
    if ( init-statement condition )

init-statement:
    simple-declaration

simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list;
    decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifier [ identifier-list ] initializer ;
```

It's summarized above from all over the standard (with some optional things removed for brevity), but the start point is at [[stmt.select]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.select#1).

The crux of the matter is that a `simple-declaration` is either a comma separated list of declarators that introduce objects of the same type<sup>1</sup> (`decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list;`) **or** a single structured binding (the second, rather verbose line under `simple-declaration`).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Not *strictly* the same type (`int x, *y;`), but the the point should be clear.</sub>